# Angular CLI - unable to use custom environment file for testing

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-cli, angular8

I try to run `ng test` with a specific flag configured in custom environment file.

My @angular/cli version is 8.3.21.

1. My first attempt was to run `ng test --environment=<custom>`.

I got error:

> Unknown option: '--environment'.

I saw that --environment option is valid (https://angular.io/cli/test).
Could the documentation be out of date?

2. Later I tried another approach - use the angular.json like this:

```
{
...
    "architect": {
        "test": {
            "builder": "@angular-builders/jest:run",
            "options": {},
            "configurations": {
                "customTest": {
                    "fileReplacements": [
                        {
                            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                            "with": "src/environments/environment.customTest.ts"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to run this `ng test -c=customTest` and I got this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot convert object to primitive value

Note - I can't use the options attribute to configure the file replacement.

Thanks.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce your second option, no issues. Maybe it's time to delete the *node_modules* folder and *package-lock.json*, then run `npm install`, and try again.

Comment: @R.Richards, Thanks. It's work for karma. Jest builder is not support fileReplacements. this is the reason that I can't do it. 
I successfully did it as described here: https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/issues/174